# Cumulative Column that starts at Zero every Year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data from January 1st 2008 to today ordered by date in the first column of a table Ratio.

I have values in the second column. I was able to do a cumulative third column with the following code but I don't know how to make it re-start every January 1st to have cumulative per year.

```
SELECT 
    t3.Date, 
    SUM(cumul) AS cumul 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t1.Date, 
        t1.nb, 
        SUM(t2.nb) AS cumul   
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            Ratio.Date, 
            SUM(DailyValue) AS Nb
        FROM Ratio
        GROUP BY Ratio.Date
    )t1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            Ratio.Date, 
            SUM(DailyValue) AS nb
        FROM Ratio
        GROUP BY Ratio.Date
    ) t2 
        ON t1.Date >= t2.Date
    GROUP BY t1.Date, t1.nb
)t3
GROUP BY PnLDate,nb
ORDER BY pnldate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way using window function `SUM`

```
select Date,
    sum(sum(DailyValue)) over (
        partition by year(date) order by date
        ) as cumul
from Ratio
group by Date
order by Date;
```

Comment: why  `sum(sum(DailyValue))` ? a  `sum(DailyValue)` is enough no ? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1e120/1

Comment: @Blag - What if there are multiple rows with same date? See this example - http://rextester.com/VGLF85912